# C# SocketException (0x80004005) on every two attempt

Tags: c#, sockets, socketexception

My program creates a new TCP Socket, sends a request to a server and reads the response. If the response is requested, the program sends an acknowledge and if not it sends a negative acknowledge. This send and receive part work as intended.

The problem is that when i call the method a second time it throws `SocketException (0x80004005)`. The third attempt works just as intended but every two attempt to send request to socket will fail.

```
public void Send(byte[] request)
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024];
    var received = 0;
    try
    {
        using (var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
        {
            socket.Connect(Address, Port);
            socket.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;

            socket.Send(request);

            while ((received = socket.Receive(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                var response = buffer.Take(received);

                if (IsRequested(response))
                {
                    socket.Send(ACK);
                    var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                    return;
                }
            }
            socket.Send(NAK);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

I have tried disconnecting, closing, disposing and every possible combination of the three without success.

I discovered that if I throw an exception right after sending the acknowledge, the method will work every time!

```
    if (IsRequested(response))
    {
        socket.Send(ACK);
        var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        throw new Exception("Deliberate exception");
    }
```

**My question:** 
Why do I get `SocketException (0x80004005)` every two attempt if I don't throw an exception?

Comment: You can only have one connection with the same three parameters 1) Source IP address 2) Destination IP address 3) Port number.  So you cannot crate a 2nd socket with the same three parameters.  Make sure your code is only calling the socket constructor once [new Socket()].

Comment: Improve your error reporting, e.Message does not tell you much.  Use e.ToString(), copy/paste what you see in your question if you still need help.

Comment: @jdweng The socket is disposed after each call to the method?

Comment: @HansPassant `e.ToString()` tells the connection failed because the established connection to the host is no longer working. It also tells the exception was thrown on socket.Receive(buffer)

Comment: Why close connection between messages?  I know there are a lot of examples of closing connection after each message, but I think it creates more issues than it solves.

Comment: Any windows error code ending in 5 denotes an 'acces denied'. Perhaps the port is stil bound / not available the second time round?